# Read each line of a file and give each an ID - Python

Tags: python

I need to read each line of an input file and assign each one it's own ID so that it can be identified later on.

This would be simple if I knew the amount of lines that the file would have or if it were short but I need to make it able to take a file with any number of lines

For example the trial file I am using contains this:

```
somewhere over rainbow bluebirds fly birds fly over rainbow why why
double time population long takes population double size
whoa full rainbow way double rainbow double rainbow way
```

and I need to read each line individually and assign it an ID so that `somewhere over rainbow bluebirds fly birds fly over rainbow why why` is assigned ID 1 and so forth.

I can't seem to be able to find a way to dynamically create variables/variable names and I don't know of any other way of automatically assigning IDs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you're looking for is a dictionary or a list. Is this homework? It smells a lot like homework.

Comment: I reopened this question as the duplicate target has been deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You can store the lines in a dictionary, with the keys as the ids:

```
with open(myfile, 'r') as f:
    lines = {i: line for i, line in emumerate(f, 1)}
```

This will produce a dictionary with numbers from 1 as keys:

```
{
    1: "somewhere over rainbow bluebirds fly birds fly over rainbow why why",
    2: "double time population long takes population double size",
    3: "whoa full rainbow way double rainbow double rainbow way"
}
```

The second argument to the [enumerate function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) sets the starting number for the enumeration, so in this case we start indexing from one; the default is zero if no starting number is provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line_no,line in enumerate(file,1):
    ...
```

`line_no` would be your `id` ... I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict to store the lines with the id

Here an example

```
rows = {}
n = 1
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        rows[n] = line
        n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use a list, with position as ID:

```
ls = []
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        ls.append(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary seems like a good solution for this problem. I would also use enumerate to get the line number automatically.

```
file_name = 'text.txt'
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    indexes = {index:value for index, value in enumerate(f)}
>>>indexes[0]
'somewhere over rainbow bluebirds fly birds fly over rainbow why why\n'
```